# Migrating a websphere 8 liberty profile web app to tomcat 8, login always give 408

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm migrating a old websphere 8 liberty profile struts web app that was using java 6 and spring 3.1.14 to tomcat 8 with jdk 8 and spring 3.2.18.
After fighting with the configuration, the version and the pom, I managed to load the main page and login page.

After converting the liberty  &  user and roles to the tomcat-users.xml file in tomcat, I managed to login but it give a http 408 error instantly.
If I try to login using a user that don't exist or with the wrong password it block me properly.
I've tried many suggestion on SO but nothing seem to work.
Maybe the redirection for liberty doesn't work the same way than in tomcat and the setting must be change.
There's a strange behaviours since the change to tomcat:
With liberty the login page showed up before the index, but on tomcat the index appear first then the login appear when clicking on a link on the login page.

Did you any of you had this issues with http 408 when configuring a tomcat server?

Here my configuration so far:

-> server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">    
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

-> context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TheDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                   username="secret" password="secret" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = toto)(PORT = 2222))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = none.offyourbusiness.com)))"/>

</Context>
```

-> tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
 <role rolename="BasicAccess"/>
 <role rolename="StaffAccess"/>
 <role rolename="AdminAccess"/>
 <role rolename="ProfileAccess"/>
 
 <user username="basicUser" password="toto" roles="BasicAccess"/>
 <user username="staffUser" password="toto" roles="BasicAccess,StaffAccess"/>
 <user username="profileUser" password="toto" roles="BasicAccess,ProfileAccess"/>
 <user username="superUser" password="toto" roles="BasicAccess,AdminAccess"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

-> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>ViewerWeb</display-name>

    <!-- Spring configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!--  FILTER   -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.project.viewer.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
 
    <!--  STRUTS SERVLET  -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/document/struts-config-document.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/access/struts-config-access.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/profile/struts-config-profile.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/report/struts-config-report.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/status/struts-config-status.xml,
                /WEB-INF/modules/roadblock/struts-config-roadblock.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/chain-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>999</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>999</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        
        <!--  SECURITY ROLES  -->
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>BasicAccess</role-name>
            <role-link>BasicAccess</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>StaffAccess</role-name>
            <role-link>StaffAccess</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>AdminAccess</role-name>
            <role-link>AdminAccess</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>ProfileAccess</role-name>
            <role-link>ProfileAccess</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!--  PAGES  -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/notauthorized.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/notauthorized.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <!--  SECURITY CONSTRAINT - DOCUMENT -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Document</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/document.do</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/download.do</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>BasicAccess</role-name>
            <role-name>StaffAccess</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    
    <!--  SECURITY CONSTRAINT - ADMINISTRATION  -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Report Access Manager And View Authorizations</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/report.do</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/access.do</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>AdminAccess</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    
    <!--  SECURITY CONSTRAINT - PROFILE MANAGER -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Profile Manager</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/profile.do</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ProfileAccess</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!--  LOGIN FORM  -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.jsp?msg=error</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    
    <!--  ROLES  -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>BasicAccess</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>StaffAccess</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>AdminAccess</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ProfileAccess</role-name>
    </security-role>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I can't help with configuring Tomcat, but is there are reason you're using Tomcat over Open Liberty? You would need minimal, if any server configuration changes, just the same jdk and spring updates. Tomcat 8 is already out of support, with known unfixed CVEs, where you could run the latest version of Open Liberty with all security updates, and both are open source.

Comment: it's a company mandate to migrate to tomcat, currently our older app are all on tomcat 8.5. Perhaps I can check if they can make an exception for this app that on life support since 2012. Once everything is working on tomcat we will adress the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and testing it seem that the problem is a session.invalidate() in the login.jsp file.

The seem to work fine when deployed on WAS liberty on a remote server.
but on a local install with tomcat, it seem to cause the problem.

So on a local tomcat install this need to be commented and everything then work fine.

```html
<%
 //the next line need to be commented for the login to work and not return a 408 http error.
    session.invalidate();
 %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Security Login Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body onload="document.getElementById('j_username').focus();">
<h2>Login Page</h2>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="j_security_check">
<p>
<font color="red">
<% 
    if ("error".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("msg"))){
        out.println("Invalid credential...");
    }
%>
</font>
<br/>
<font size="2"> <strong> Please, enter your login credentials: </strong></font>
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong> user name </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" name="j_username" id="j_username"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong> password </strong></td>
    <td><input type="password" size="20" name="j_password"></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit">


</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```